# Set TIMER interrupt int STM32F4 Discovery

Tags: stm32f4

How can I know exactly address of TIMER2 in Interrupt Set-Enable Registers (NVIC registers) to set for TIMER2 interrupt. Document " cortex m4 processor manual" just gives address of interrupt set enable registers from 0xE000E100-0xE000E11C not specific address bit for TIMER2.

Answer (score 1):

With reference to the [v7 reference manual for the STM32F407](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00031020.pdf), table 61 on p369 contains the list of interrupt vectors and their bit position (0-255) in the NVIC_ISER/ICER registers.